# String.replace removing backslash

Tags: c#, asp.net, replace

I have a question and I am sure it is simple but its not working in my code. I am creating a log file and I want to concatenate the date to the file name so they know when the log was generated. My string.replace isn't removing "\" from my date which I have converted to string.

See code below:

```
        string DateNow = Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now);
        DateNow = DateNow.Substring(0, 10);
        DateNow.Replace(@"\\", "-");

        string FileName = "log" + DateNow + ".txt";

        // Write values to textfile and save to Log folder
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Log" + FileName))) 
        {
            sw.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now);
            sw.WriteLine("New user created");
            sw.WriteLine("Username is: " + username);
            sw.WriteLine("Password is: " + password);
            sw.WriteLine("Company is: " + company);
            sw.WriteLine("Email is: " + email);
            sw.Dispose();
            sw.Close(); 
        }
```

This will throw an exception because file names in windows can't contain \ character. Any ideas why the replace method isn't working?

Thanks.

Comment: System.DateTime.Now.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy');

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's working, but you are not storing the result. It needs to read

```
DateNow = DateNow.Replace(@"\", "-");
```

But that's simply a patch for a bad solution. Why not do it the right way in the first place? Use `DateTime.ToString` with a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) instead. For example:

```
string DateNow = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); // or any other format
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of using Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") as a way of setting the date format.

Comment: I have marked this as the correct answer because Jon makes a good point about using custom format rather than using replace to remove char.

Answer (score 2):

You've already escaped the backslash using the @ symbol, so the replace function is looking for "\\", not "\". To make your code work, change it to:

```
DateNow = DateNow.Replace(@"\", "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct `System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy');`

**OR**
`DateTime` Date With Time

```
string newDate = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace('/','-');
```

**or** `Date` Only

```
string newDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString().Replace('/','-');
```

**out put**

9-27-2012 5:20:12 PM

Answer (score 0):

nothing to do `split` or `convert ToString()`

```
string DateNow = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

insted `yyyy-MM-dd` you also write `yyyy/MM/dd`

Check this link for more date formate [Dateformate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)